# How to create vbscript or bat file to overrite an existing xml file

Tags: xml, vbscript, batch-file

One of the user of our application has a xml named `zean.xml` file located in the location  `C:\ProgramData\Secon\levrer\8.6.7\team\lead\Captain folder`. But now i feel i need to replace the xml file content with the following content as a temperory workaround .I thought of to write vbscript or bat file so that i can give to the user who are using this xml file. can any body provide me the vbscript code or bat file for rewriting the xml file with following content

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <TestSchema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TestSchema.xsd">
  <UserZone>
  <Label>All</Label> 
  <ID>8c19c791-32d6-4ad1-8504-c3387b5a0096</ID> 
  </UserZone>
 <ZoneMgGrpCollection>
  <Owner>8c19c791-32d6-4ad1-8504-c3387b5a0096</Owner> 
  <MgGrpID>5f498b70-ee75-4ff0-8808-b9ba492b7f8a</MgGrpID> 
  </ZoneMgGrpCollection>
  </TestSchema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the text o a new XML-file and then copy it over the other one.
You can do both manual or by script but i don't see why you would do it by script since this is clearly a one time operation.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set tf=fso.OpenTextFile ("new.xml",ForWriting,CreateIfNeeded)
tf.write "<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes"" ?>  "
'repeat this for the other lines
tf.close
fso.CopyFile("new.xml", "C:\ProgramData\Secon\levrer\8.6.7\team\lead\Captain folder\",True)
```